# wordpress login refresh with ELB

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have this WP website (fresh install with latest code) and I want to make it run under AWS ELB.

First step I've set up is the ELB with one instance. I've set up RDS and everything is working perfect. The problem appears when I run the second instance. In the login form the password is empty on sending so the page just refreshes but not all the time. If I test in firefox I send the password but I get redirect on wp-admin. I've also set up ElasticCache to handle the session. I am using PHP7 and UBUNTU 16.04. If someone is having a clue why is this happening I will appreciate it very much. Thank you

Later edit: 
The PHP Session is shared between the ec2 instances and hosted in ElastiCache (Memcached). So in php.ini, at the session section, I use memcached. If I have only one ec2 under the ELB, I can login to the admin and all is perfect. The problem is when have both of them under ELB (the exact same config) the website is working but the login in the admin no any more. Does someone have any idea/clue/suggestion about this matter? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this issue. The problem i had was on the ELB with the sticky sessions. I just enabled it and set a time of 3600 and now wordpress in login in users. A question remains with the real ELB power. If you do this sticky session I found some documentation that says the user is bind to one single EC2 exclusively .. feel free to comment over this. Thanks again